# How to calculate the 1st and 3th quartile of a list without import?

Tags: python, list, quartile

I need to make a function q1 that calculates the 1st quartile of a list called: lst.
i am not allowed to use any imports!
When i run my function the answer is not correct. What can i change?

```
def q1(lst):
    lst.sort()

    middle = len(lst)//2

    k1 = median([middle])
    return k1
```

This is my median function:

```
def median(lst):
    lst.sort()
    half_list = len(lst) // 2
    even = lst[half_list]
    odd = lst[-half_list-1]
    return (even + odd) / 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented a simple quantile function that uses linear interpolation to get the value between two indices, if required.

```py
def calc_quantile(lst, q):
    s_lst = sorted(lst)

    idx = (len(s_lst) - 1)*q
    int_idx = int(idx)
    remainder = idx % 1
    if remainder > 0:
        lower_val = s_lst[int_idx]
        upper_val = s_lst[int_idx + 1]

        return lower_val * (1 - remainder) + upper_val * remainder
    else:
        return s_lst[int_idx]
```

Edited my reply with below extended code, to match your test-cases:

```py
def calc_quantile(lst, q, method='linear'):
    if not lst:
        return ValueError("list is empty, cannot calculate quantile")
    if not 0 <= q <= 1:
        return ValueError("q must be in the domain 0 to 1")
    if method not in ['linear', 'left-side', 'average']:
        return NotImplementedError("the chosen method has not been implemented")

    s_lst = sorted(lst)

    idx = (len(s_lst) - 1)*q
    int_idx = int(idx)
    remainder = idx % 1
    if remainder > 0 and method != 'left-side':
        lower_val = s_lst[int_idx]
        upper_val = s_lst[int_idx + 1]

        if method == 'linear':
            return lower_val * (1 - remainder) + upper_val * remainder
        else:
            return (lower_val + upper_val) / 2
    else:
        return s_lst[int_idx]


print(calc_quantile([1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 2], 0.25, 'left-side'))   # 2
print(calc_quantile([1, 3, 5, 6, 1, 4, 2], 0.25, 'left-side'))  # 1
print(calc_quantile([1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 2, 4, 1], 0.25, 'average'))  # 1.5
```

Comment: I can only use 1 parameter, lst to my function.How can i remove the q parameter?

Comment: you could just make lambdas for each of the cases you needed, for example
`quartile_1st = lambda lst: calc_quantile(lst, 0.25)`   
`median = lambda lst: calc_quantile(lst, 0.5)`   
`quartile_3rd = lambda lst: calc_quantile(lst, 0.75)`

Comment: This works, however it gives me the wrong answer. i have another function which test if the answer is true and it returns false.

Comment: Well there are several interpretations as to how you wish to calculate quantiles. The approach I added above uses linear interpolation between points - Perhaps your check function is always using the left-side index?

I am quite confident that my function works as intended, so you need to give some more information if you want further clarifications

Comment: These are the results of my test function:   
        ([1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 2], 2.0),
        ([1, 3, 5, 6, 1, 4, 2], 1.0),
        ([1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 2, 4, 1], 1.5)

Comment: I assume this is results for the first quartile => But it looks like your test function is inconsistent though. The first two examples you provide are consistent with a left-side index quantile, while the last example you provide is consistent with a non-weighted average of the two indices the slice falls between

Comment: I edited my reply to show you the different calculation methods and results.

Comment: Thanks for your help! this is for a small assignment for school. My teacher delivered the test function. Is this function wrong?

Comment: If not wrong, it is at least inconsistent in the method it applies for calculating results between two indices.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I am a beginner and i'm learning a lot from this.

Answer (score 2):

The median is the middle item of the sorted list, i.e `len(lst)//2`.
Accordingly, what is the first and third quartile of a list?

```
firstQIndex = len(lst)//4
thirdQIndex = (3*len(lst))//4
firstQ = lst[firstQIndex]
thirdQ = lst[thirdQIndex]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function (standalone, no imports):

```
def quantile(x, y):
    n = int(round(y * len(x) + 0.5))
    return x[n-1]
```

And call like:

```
print(quantile(myList, 0.1))
print(quantile(myList, 0.3))
```